# Decrease the margin and push down content below

Tags: css, margin

When the link stay closed it has a very big bottom margin. I need decrease the margin and push down content below upon the slidedown.

```css
#menu-toggle2 {
  display: none;
}

#collapse-menu2 {
  transition: transform 0.3s;
  transform-origin: top;
}

input:not(:checked)~#collapse-menu2 {
  transform: scaleY(0);
}

.pinkdok {
  color: #FF4870;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h4>Архив прошлых уведомлений</h4>
<input id="menu-toggle2" type="checkbox">
<label id="menu-label" for="menu-toggle2">
  <h6 class="pinkdok">Подробнее</h6>
</label>
<ul id="collapse-menu2">
  <li>Должники на 01.01.2019<br>
    <a class="pinkdok" href="https://domain.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Dolgi01012019g.xls.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Скачать документ (.pdf)</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your elements aren't visible within the DOM, that doesn't mean they don't take their space. The `UL` element still had some height. Although this is a quick fix. This will help you forward.

For example this CSS:

```
opacity: 0; /* The element is invisible, but still takes space */
---
display: none; /* The element is invisible, and won't take any space */
```

Within your example, you used `scaleY()` but the element will still take it's space within the DOM.

```css
#menu-toggle2 {
  display: none;
}

#collapse-menu2 {
  transition: transform 0.3s;
  transform-origin: top;
  height: auto;  /* added to example */
}

input:not(:checked)~#collapse-menu2 {
  transform: scaleY(0);
  height: 0; /* added to example */
}

.pinkdok {
  color: #FF4870;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Not question related */

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<h4>Архив прошлых уведомлений</h4>
<input id="menu-toggle2" type="checkbox">
<label id="menu-label" for="menu-toggle2">
  <h6 class="pinkdok">Подробнее</h6>
</label>
<ul id="collapse-menu2">
  <li>Должники на 01.01.2019<br>
    <a class="pinkdok" href="https://gbu-chs.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Dolgi01012019g.xls.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Скачать документ (.pdf)</a></li>
</ul>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec elit nibh, suscipit placerat euismod et, interdum at metus. Cras sit amet hendrerit risus. Phasellus porttitor, eros vitae elementum consequat, leo enim varius nibh, sit amet ullamcorper massa
  lorem id magna. Aenean vel risus in ligula iaculis facilisis. Curabitur ut feugiat nulla, ac bibendum odio. Suspendisse dignissim ligula vel diam condimentum aliquam. Etiam tincidunt eleifend nisi eget feugiat. Donec ligula lorem, dignissim vitae varius
  quis, pulvinar vel nibh. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.</p>
```

Comment: Note: Yes I'm aware there is still space under the "Подробнее" but that is  the styling giving with this example. His code the space underneath was bigger.